# Can native vhd booted Windows see the host filesystem on which the VHD resides?

Tags: vhd, boot-to-vhd

When using Native VHD boot, can Windows users see/read/write the host's file system on which the VHD resides?

Comment: I am reasonable sure once the VHD is booted you can't access the host.  The only way to ask the host would something like creating a file share with the host.

Comment: cybernard, thx, but you don't seem to know what native boot is. "Native boot allows virtual hard disks (VHDs) to run on a computer without a virtual machine or hypervisor." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799282(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you native boot a VHD, you can see the host file system that contains the VHD.  The file metadata like last modified is also updated as the OS runs.  On my test systems, it mounts after the VHD drive letter (so it is typically D:). I've used this fact to store data that needs to persist between two different VHDs that I boot to.